# Repairing Visual Studio 2013 with Update 4

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, repair

If I do a Repair of Visual Studio from "Add or remove programs", do I need to re-run Update 4 afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from add or remove programs,
But I think it would be more wise to re-download the installer and 
repair the software.
It is not necessary to run update 4 afterwards.